# point biserial and p-value

Tags: r, correlation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to get a point biserial correlation between a continuous vocabulary score and syntactic productivity (dichotomous: productive vs not_productive).

I tried both the ltm packages

```
> biserial.cor (lol$voc1_tvl, lol$synt, use = c("complete.obs"))
```

and the polycor package

```
> polyserial( lol$voc1_tvl, lol$synt, ML = FALSE, control = list(), std.err = FALSE, maxcor=.9999, bins=4)
```

The problem is that neither test gives me a p-value

How could I run a point biserial correlation test and get the associated p-value or alternatively calculate the p-value myself?

Comment: Friendly note: when trying to put quote into a question or answer, either add 4 spaces before the line (vs the '>' symbol) or select all the code you want and press the '{}' button to automatically do so.  Also, making a reproducible example will increase your chances of getting a question answered.

Answer (score 3):

Since the point biserial correlation is just [a particular case of the popular Peason's product-moment coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/105553/27433), you can use `cor.test` to approximate (more on that later) the correlation between a continuous X and a dichotomous Y. For example, given the following data:

```
set.seed(23049)
x <- rnorm(1e3)
y <- sample(0:1, 1e3, replace = TRUE)
```

Running `cor.test(x, y)` will give you the information you want.

```
    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x and y
t = -1.1971, df = 998, p-value = 0.2316
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.09962497  0.02418410
sample estimates:
        cor 
-0.03786575
```

As an indication of the similarity between the coefficients, notice how the calculated correlation of `-0.03786575` is similar to what `ltm::biserial.cor` gives you:

```
> library(ltm)
> biserial.cor(x, y, level = 2)
[1] -0.03784681
```

The diference lies on the fact that `biserial.cor` is calculated on the population, with standard deviations being divided by `n`, where `cor` and `cor.test` calculate standard deviations for a sample, dividing by `n - 1`.

As cgage noted, you can also use the `polyserial()` function, which in my example would yield

```
> polyserial(x, y, std.err = TRUE)

Polyserial Correlation, 2-step est. = -0.04748 (0.03956)
Test of bivariate normality: Chisquare = 1.891, df = 5, p = 0.864
```

Here, I believe the difference in the calculated correlation (-0.04748) is due to `polyserial` using an optimization algorithm to approximate the calculation (which is unnecessary unless Y has more than two levels).

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ggplot2` dataset `mpg` as a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
# Use class as dichotomous variable (must subset)
newData = subset(mpg, class == 'midsize' | class == 'compact')

# Now getting p-value
library(ltm)
polyserial(newData$cty,newData$class, std.err = T)
```

You will see all the output you desire using `std.err=T` in `polyserial`

Comment: thank you so much for answering. So, If so understand correctly, the formula is: polyserial (dichotomous_variable, continuous_variable, std.err = T). Am I getting it right?

Comment: Close, just swap the dichotomous and continuous variable. You can use `?polyserial` for more details. Good luck!